# Не могу скачать Roblox Roshade

Tags: roblox

скачал Roshade и что бы увидеть меню шейдеров,нужно нажать “F7” но при нажатии ничего не происходит,как исправить?Просто в шейдерах вообще не разбираюсь,можно ли их на ноут скачать?